# Ajax Function Not Being Called

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

So What I'm trying to do is, create an alert using java script. And if the person presses OK
it will send a variable to the handler and the handler will send an email. The following code is what I have, but I'm having trouble debugging it. As of right now I have this:

THE IF STATEMENT, CLICKING OKAY:

```
    var pressed = confirm("Click okay to email users of video upload or Cancel to keep   adding videos");
        if (pressed == true)
        {
            var variable = 44;
            emailParticipants(variable);
            alert ("email sent");
        }
```

FUNCTION THAT SENDS TO HANDLER:

```
function emailParticipants(sessionID)
    {

    var ID = sessionID;


       if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
       {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
       }
       else
       {// code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
       }
       xmlhttp.open("GET","http://www.website.ca/portal/folder/HandleEmail.php?sessID="+ID,true);
       xmlhttp.send();    

  }
```

HANDLER:

```
$SessID = $_GET['ID'];
<?php
$toEmail = 'someone@hotmail.com';
$toName = "TEST TEST";
<script>alert ("works");</script>
.
.. 
....
```

The rest of the handler functing just sends the email. I can't catch where the mistake is.

Comment: I can't see why the handler function would send an email. You have no code there that would do that, and it will bail out when you hit `<script>alert ("works");</script>` since that isn't PHP.

Comment: You've also failed to say what you expect to happen that doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you are invoking the handler via AJAX. The `alert()` method is inside the page the handler returns ... but you aren't doing anything with that page. You make a request and forget about the response. The browser doesn't execute the response from an AJAX call, so the code with the `alert` never executes.

By the way, you ** never ** should send e-mails (or do any other change in the server but returning information) with a GET request. GET requests can be cached, or even prefetched, causing emails to be sent when not requested, or not be sent when requested. I'd change the request type to `POST`.

If you want your `alert`, you need to change your client code and add this:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","http://www.website.ca/portal/folder/HandleEmail.php?sessID="+ID,true);
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
         if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
             alert('works!');
         } else {
             alert('Failed! ' + xmlhttp.statusText);
         }
    }
}
xmlhttp.send();
```

I think you are a bit lost about AJAX. You should read [more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX)

Comment: Yea I'm pretty new to this, and thank you for the link I will definetly read up on it.